# Display .jsonld Files in gh-pages

Tags: github, github-pages, json-ld

I'm trying to display JSON-LD data using the .jsonld extension in our gh-pages in the browser instead. I'd like to use the actual files as a reference. We can serve them as downloadable files but would prefer to display the raw data. We're using a Jekyll theme. Is there a config setting for this? Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote? Bad idea? Not possible? Bad question?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT that's not possible. You could use Gists instead or directly link to the file on GitHub